# Multiply or add more zeroes

Tags: bash, awk

```
cat file.txt

20150101
2015010103
2015010106
201501010901
2015010112
20150101150130
2015010118
20150101210150
```

The file contains dates in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format. Somewhere its length is 8, 10, 12, 14.
I want the output as

```
20150101000000
20150101030000
20150101060000
20150101090100
20150101120000
20150101150130
20150101180000
20150101210150
```

where the HHMMSS are missing, put 000000.
I am trying to read the whole file in array and line by line like:

```
mapfile -s 0 -t strdate < file.txt
for pp in ${strdate[@]};do
  if [ `echo ${#pp}` == 8 ]; then
  newTime=$(( $pp*10000 ))
  ...
  fi
done
```

any direct awk solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` in your awk:

```
awk '{s=sprintf("%-14s", $1); gsub(/ /, "0", s); print s}' file
20150101000000
20150101030000
20150101060000
20150101090100
20150101120000
20150101150130
20150101180000
20150101210150
```

Alternatively following `printf` will also work:

```
awk '{printf "%-d%0" (14-length($1)) "s\n", $1, ""}' file
20150101000000
20150101030000
20150101060000
20150101090100
20150101120000
20150101150130
20150101180000
20150101210150
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
awk '{while(length($0)<14)$0=$0 0}1' file

20150101000000
20150101030000
20150101060000
20150101090100
20150101120000
20150101150130
20150101180000
20150101210150
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{i=length($0);while(i++<14)$0=$0"0"}1' File
```

**Logic:**
Append `0`s to each line as long as the line length is less than `14 (as per question)` and print every line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting way of doing it with `coreutils` and `bash` redirection:

```
printf "%-14s\n" $(<file.txt) | tr ' ' 0
```

This assumes that there is no extra space in `file.txt`.

Output:

```
20150101000000
20150101030000
20150101060000
20150101090100
20150101120000
20150101150130
20150101180000
20150101210150
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
~$ awk '{x=$0;for(i=length(x);i<14;i++)x=x"0";print x}' file.txt
20150101000000
20150101030000
20150101060000
20150101090100
20150101120000
20150101150130
20150101180000
20150101210150
```

`length(string)` gives the number of characters in string. If string is a number, it gives the length of the string representing that number.

So from the length of the number to 14, concatenate "0" to the "number".

Answer (score 0):

Using Python:

```
$ cat file
20150101
2015010103
2015010106
201501010901
2015010112
20150101150130
2015010118
20150101210150

$ python -c $'import sys\nfor line in sys.stdin:\n\tprint "%.14s" % (line.rstrip() + "0"*14)' < file
20150101000000
20150101030000
20150101060000
20150101090100
20150101120000
20150101150130
20150101180000
20150101210150
```

Explanation:

1. For every line in input, append 14 zeroes.
2. Out of the generated line, print first 14 characters.

The python script above in non-one-liner form would look like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print "%.14s" % (line.rstrip() + "0"*14)
```

Same logic under `sed`:

```
sed -r  's/$/00000000000000/;s/(.{14}).*/\1/' < file
```